# Passing rails requests through a series of controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The question is generalized but I want to ask about a specific case which I want to solve.

I'm working with a really really smelly code base of e-commerce app and I want to refactor it. I thought I should start with the User authentication.

#### Problem

Before every action in any controller, we check if the user is of a particular type: `Guest`, `Signed-In` or `Admin` and also, if the user is allowed to access this action based on the type. If all the conditions are met, then the action is executed. And this happens in majority of the actions in majority of the controllers.

#### My thinking

I know this code is smelly because checking if the user is of a particular type and (s)he has access to an action is not the action's responsibility.

#### My solution which may or may not be possible

We can make a `SessionsController` (or some other name) and let it handle the authentication and authorization part. But I want the `SessionsController` to do its job automatically before every request. *i.e.* Every request should go through the `SessionsController` and then this controller will decide whether or not to forward the request to the appropriate controller.

I search Google for this but didn't find anything. So my logical conclusion is that passing a request through a series of controllers might not be possible. But I'm not sure. So if it is possible, guide me how to do it. And if it is not possible, then suggest any other way to do it.

Comment: If you're downvoting a question, at least give a reason for the downvote and suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect example in which one or multiple `before_action` can be used. You can place a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
private
def authorize_admin
  render status: 401 unless current_user? && current_user.admin?
end
```

Then you can declare in any controller in which you want to run this method before running any action.

```
# in any controller - even the ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate
```

You can configure `before_action` to only run on certain conditions or with certain actions. Just a have a look at the how to use [Filters in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).